# Setting the link to HTML in JSP using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I try the tutorial on the [Spring MVC textbox example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-textbox-example/). Working well, however I have no idea about handling the name of link.

The only working one is `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/textbox.html` and I don't know how to change the `textbox.html` part to anything else.

According comments and all the information about I realized it's named according the controlling class.

> TextBoxController.java -> textbox.html

Here is the related code:

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="nch.customer.controller.TextBoxController">
    <property name="formView" value="CustomerForm" />
    <property name="successView" value="CustomerSuccess" />
    // Anything to put here?

    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="nch.customer.validator.CustomerValidator" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**TextBoxController.java**

```
public class TextBoxController extends SimpleFormController {

public TextBoxController() {
    setCommandClass(Customer.class);
    setCommandName("customerForm");
    // Or anything to put here?
}

@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit (
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
    Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {

    Customer customer = (Customer) command;
    return new ModelAndView("CustomerSuccess","customer",customer);
}
```

My question is. How to change the link name without changing the name of class? Ex:

> TextBoxController.java -> txb.html

Comment: There will be a URL mapping somewhere, either as an Annotation or in the XML. Can you find and show us that please?

Comment: @Steward I have done it by the linked example, using XML and no Annotations. There are no changes except the package names.

Comment: See Rocherlee's answer. He's done it with `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`. That's what I'm talking about. You to specify somewhere the mapping, otherwise you'll get a default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bean `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is doing the conversion
`TextBoxController -> /textbox*`

With this config, both `textbox.html` and `textboxxx.html` work.

> ... to take the short name of the Class, remove the 'Controller' suffix if it exists and return the remaining text, lower-cased, as the mapping, with a leading /.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
```

Replace it with another bean `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, and provide `id` for `TextBoxController` bean when you want to customize your path. Your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` will look like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="mappings">
    <props>
       <prop key="/txb.html">txtboxController</prop>
     </props>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txtboxController" class="nch.customer.controller.TextBoxController">
   <property name="formView" value="CustomerForm" />
   <property name="successView" value="CustomerSuccess" />
   <property name="validator">
      <bean class="nch.customer.validator.CustomerValidator" />
   </property>
</bean>
```